# Does Apple change OS X operating systems between the GM and the final release?

Tags: preview, macos

For instance, I've found quite a few bugs while working with the Mountain Lion Golden Master. Is there any chance Apple might fix these in the public release?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Good question! Thanks for asking! Especially as it *is* on topic for the site!

Comment: Golden Master is something that developers use - and as such is off-topic for this site. Feel free to discuss on chat or in meta - there is a nice answer on the "community bulletin" to the right explaining the rationale for this.

Comment: But it's not a development question! This question IS within the guidelines! The goal of the rules is to keep this board away from "coding help" style questions. One could also argue that any question about OS X is a development question because developers tend to use OS X to make apps. Closing this is ridiculous. It was a good question that got a good response form the community. Great work there @bmike.

Comment: We don't entertain questions on software that isn't available to the general public. Full stop. Secondly, GM is label - not a promise. It doesn't change unless there is a reason to - it is pure speculation whether any particular build will ship - even based on the numbers for past performance, it's like guessing the winner of a horse race. No one knows - so how on earth would you know which answer to choose until 10.8 is released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a first time for everything but, but basically: no.

Unless you have found the mother of all security bugs, so humiliating that it would overshadow Apple's entire Mountain Lion release, the bug to end all bugs and live on in infamy, it just is not going to happen.

Not to mention, fixing and testing bugs generally takes time. The fastest Apple bug fix ever, to my knowledge, took [two days](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-17700824) but that's very unusual for a company its size. In general it takes weeks, in many cases months, even years.

Comment: The fix would probably get rolled into a 10.8.1 ... update..